# Upper bound for trace of a certain inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am stuck with the following problem of finding an upper bound for the modulus
$$
\big|\,\text{tr}\bigg(\big(I - Th(\lambda)\big)^{-1}Th(\lambda)\bigg)\big|
$$
in terms of $\lambda$. Here $T \in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $h$ is a $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$-valued function of a complex variable $\lambda$. Of particular interest would be the function
$$
h(\lambda) := e^{i(A - \lambda I)} 
$$ 
where $A$ is a hermitian matrix and $\lambda$ is purely imaginary.

The motivation for this problem is an investigation into the integrability of a certain contour integral along a contour that escapes to infinity.

I am not sure how to proceed here. For the scalar case this is certainly feasible but for higher dimensions I don't know how to start - should I try to think about diagonalizing the matrix? Or maybe there are some generally known estimates for inverse matrices of the given form (such as there are for resolvents, though the above has NOT the form of a resolvent as $h$ is not necessarily a linear function). Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: About the notation, what is $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: @Alt $GL(n\mathbb{C})$ stands for the general linear group whose elements are invertible $n \times n$ matrices with complex entries.

Comment: In parts of your question $\lambda$ is complex and in others it is purely imaginary. Also, what hypothesis guarantees that $I-Th(\lambda)$ will be invertible?

Comment: @MartinArgerami In the particular case of $h(\lambda) = e^{i(A - \lambda I)}$ mentioned above I assume $\lambda$ to be purely imaginary, this functional form of $h$ is of particular interest but maybe the analysis is easier if one doesn't focus on this so I introduced the problem in more general terms. As regards the hypothesis of invertibility this is something I would have to assume anyways so let's suppose this is always the case